# Why was US v. Miller not dismissed?

Tags: united-states, constitutional-law

In US v. Miller, the court found that the National Firearms Act of 1934 was Constitutional.  The question I have is, why wasn't it dismissed considering that Miller died before the case was heard?

Wouldn't that make the case moot?

Answer (score 3):

### Miller was only one of the defendants

Two people were charged with the crime, Miller and Laycock. Miller was dead, Laycock was still alive. Following the Supreme Court [decision](https://www.law.nyu.edu/sites/default/files/ECM_PRO_060964.pdf):

> On January 8, 1940, Layton pleaded guilty to the reinstated NFA charge and Ragon sentenced him to five years probation.

So the case was not at all moot.